# tkinter: How to automatically scroll using middle mouse button?

Tags: python, tkinter

right now I have an implementation where I'm using my middle mouse button for two operations:

1. Zooming (in and out) by rolling the wheel and
2. Scrolling the wheel button to scroll(pan) left, right, top and bottom. But in this feature, I have press and **hold** the scroll button continuously, only then can I scroll.

What I wish to do is:

1. Press and release the middle mouse button to enter scrolling mode.
2. Then, simply, move the mouse left and right and, top and bottom, to scroll in the respective directions.
3. Once done, press and release the middle mouse button to come out of this mode.

It is just like how it is implemented in MS Word or Chrome browser.

Help!

Comment: It sounds like you just need to change the binding on `<Motion>`when the middle button is pressed.  What part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick simple thing of what I believe you're after.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

pressed = False

def onClick(event):
    global pressed
    pressed = not pressed # toggle pressed when clicked
    print('Pressed')

def onMove(event):
    if pressed:
        print(event.x, event.y)

root.bind('<Button-2>', onClick)
root.bind('<Motion>', onMove)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works well. typo in onclick should have been onClick. Thank you.